# Why is not texture material show on one wall but is on another?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have wall with wood assigned [image: Right wooden wall], on another wall Im doing same but it looks like [image: Wrong wooden wall]. [image: Material]

Comment: please edit your message so that the pictures are displayed inside. Either use the editor's image insertion tool, or use the markdown code `![description](link)`.

Comment: No proper UV unwrap on object 2